# How to use git in vendor folder of fork?

Tags: laravel, git, github, composer-php, fork

I always **use** composer packages in Laravel but I never **changed** one. This is my first time and I don't want to do it incorrect.

I need to use **and change** a packages `foo/bar`. Everything that follows now is just guessed:

1. I forked the repo
2. I created a `develop` branch
3. I added a vcs to my `composer.json`

```
  "require": {
    //...
    "foo/bar": "dev-develop",
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/thisisme/bar"
    }
  ],
```

3. `composer update`
4. Now I have the `thisisme/bar` fork in my `vendor` folder in `foo`.

So far so good. Now I can use my own fork.

But currently, as I don't know what is good practice to modify the repo, I cloned the repo to a completely different location. Then I push my changes there and run `composer update` in my project to get the changes. But this is a pain.

Do I need to have a sub git in my project in `vendor/foo` with
`git remote add origin https://github.com/thisisme/bar.git`. Because "git in git" feels wrong and finally is not really working as git commands seem to interact with the "parent git".

Comment: You can have two remotes in a sandbox. Use `git remote add myfork <url>`, e.g., to add your fork if the original was already `origin`, and then when you push or pull, just state the remote you want to interact with, either `origin` or `myfork` with my example. This is not a sub git, it's two parallel remotes that you can each talk to as needed.

Comment: but then I push the entire laravel project to the package. I want to keep the package separated from the laravel project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While [VonCs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72541332/367456) is correct regarding git, I'm not certainly sure that git submodule support is well aligned with `composer(1)` `vendor` dir for packages from a VCS repository. At least I have not experimented much with it and when I use a composer configuration with a VCS git repository, I normally don't need that<sup>1</sup>.

While `composer(1)` has support for git for vendor packages, it is on repository level, that is, you can have your own repository for your package (as you have configured it shown in your question) and then composer takes care of updating (or giving a warnings about local changes).

`composer(1)` supports this with its own remote for the packages (non-bare) clone (in the `source` install, read on).

So yes, what you describe (*"But this is a pain."*), is as long as you don't use it to your benefit. While you develop your (cloned) package, you don't need to run `composer update` all the time.

---

```
.git
composer.json
vendor/foo/bar/.git
```

*A Composer project with two Git repositories*

---

This is why IMHO "git in git" must not feel wrong. Similar to git sub-modules, git supports this very well. By default it even keeps track in the parent project of the current revision (changes) of the sub-project but without having the information of the remote - as it is local (*gitlink*).

You won't see this thought as within the tree, the *gitlink* would be at `vendor/foo/bar` and commonly (& given that) `vendor` is git ignored, no version tracking in the main project for `vendor/foo/bar/.git` - but there in the sub-project.

This is not a problem as Composer manages that git sub-project for you (the initial clone and further checkouts) in terms of your main project.

And git realizes it is a different project.

You should be able to `cd` into the package directory within the vendor folder (`vendor/foo/bar`) and configure your remote(s) there. You can then work within that project and `git(1)` will work there and *not* within the parent repository.

To have this work with `composer(1)` it is important that you configure composer to prefer the *source install* variant for that repository. This is the [`preferred-install`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#preferred-install) option and you can configure it for your repository specifically.

```
{
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "foo/bar": "source"
        }
    }
}
```

From the wording in your question, I assume that you have not yet configured it.

And this is somewhat important as only with the `source` install, there will be a (non-bare) git clone in `vendor/foo/bar` and therefore the git checkout with the overall git configuration within the packages folder in the `vendor` directory (as you have Github configured as the repository source and composer optimizes to take the `dist` version by default IIRC).

After you changed your configuration to the `source` install and updated it, `cd` into `vendor/foo/bar` and then run `git remote -v`. It now should show you the "composer" remote(s) for that package.

As you use the `develop` branch, you can add changes locally but mind the gap that you would also need to push them to the remote repository (Github) before you use composer again to update (at least) that `foo/bar` package - as while you use `git` for the development of the `foo/bar` package now, in your main project you use `composer` to manage the dependency.

This is the price you have on the payroll using Github instead of a configuration that is more near to the place of work, but at least locally, you can handle the package with "git in git".

This is normally straight forward. One overall price remains thought, due to managing two instead of one repository but that you can't prevent with this kind of composer project [composer only versioned vendor folder]).

> ***Note:*** If development takes longer than a few hours, it may also make sense to include the new Git sub-project in the backup routine of your parenting project, so that when you remove the folder `vendor/foo/bar` you have a backup of the (local) Git repository and working tree in it. However, this depends on the project configuration and is your own responsibility.

---

A bit of a workflow with some hints is also outlined in the composer documentation in [*Loading a package from a VCS repository*](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository).

---

<sup>1</sup> There is a type of setup for a composer project where `vendor` itself is under git version control, with that git sub-modules can work (very well), but this is most likely not the kind of setup you have for your project, so I skip it for this answer.

Comment: Agreed: VCS repository on a custom repo is the way to go. As you mentioned, it requires a strict method when pulling/pushing/composering. Another thing is that the VCS repository may be a private one. So for CI/CD like AWS EBS, you need additional SSH key storage and manipulation upon deploy, so composer can pull it. Also be careful when pushing without composer.lock, w/ new files in foo/bar used in your Laravel app, and your CI pipeline just doing a `composer install`. Without lock, old foo/bar is checked out on composer install and autoloader generation will throw as your app tries to use it

Comment: I'll go with the answer of John Zwarthoed, as it seems to be more straight forward (for me), but I'll accept your answer, as I agree, this would be the more generic better approach.

Comment: @PeterPan: Yes, thanks for that. The approach here should be compatible with Docker mounts (mind file-rights thought, perhaps start with read-only mounts so you can't modify your projects files and dependencies from within the container environment by accident). And commenting missed to hint `composer status -vv` when working with git inside the vendor so far.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with sail or docker-compose and linking the foo/bar project in the vendor dir is only a temporary until 'it works' solution you could just add it as a volume link. This is what I usually do.

Eg: I'm working on my-project in `~/projects/my-project`, I clone the `foo/bar` repo to `~/projects/bar`

Then in the docker-compose.yml I can add the volume:

```
volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - ../bar:/var/www/html/vendor/foo/bar
```

Again, this has a huge assumption on docker being used, but I like to think that everybody is using it these days.

Comment: I use docker and I like this approach very much. Do you cd into your `foo/bar` package to commit your changes?

Comment: No I usually have the `foo/bar` open in a different project tab within my IDE

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to have a sub git in my project in vendor/foo with git remote add origin https://github.com/thisisme/bar.git.

That could be achieved with a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) which allows for your parent Git repository to only store a *reference* to another repository.
You would use [`git submodule add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule/#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-add-bltbranchgt-f--force--nameltnamegt--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--ltrepositorygtltpathgt) for that.

A [`git clone --recurse-submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---recurse-submodulesltpathspecgt) would therefore clone your project with the submodule Git repository in it cloned as well, and checked out to the exact reference you previously committed.

Comment: That means even if my `vendor` folder where the fork is in is ignored by `.gitignore` this will not interact with the "parent" git?

Comment: @PeterPan Yes, a .gitignore does not influence other repositories (nested or parent)

Comment: I tried this, but this is adding the submodule to the root. This is not working for me as I need to use it in my vendor's folder to use it with composer

Comment: @PeterPan It is adding the submodule to the path you specify on `git submodule add`. It doe snot have to be the root folder.